# Combining multiple one-to-one relationships in Doctrine on inverse side of relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hoping for some help thinking this through. Say I'm working with two entities here - User and Group. For the purposes of this example, say each Group has a senior moderator and a junior moderator, both of whom are Users and are mutually exclusive (a user can only be in one group, and cannot be both the senior and junior moderator). So in Group, I might have something like:

```
class Group
{

    /**
     * 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $seniorModerator;

    /**
     * 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $juniorModerator;

}
```

Now in User, I don't care whether the user is a senior moderator or junior moderator. I just want to be able to return what group a user is in. I know I'll have to add mappedBys in the Group properties, but I'm sort of stumped because I know I can't have two mappedBys assigned to the same thing ($group for example).

Would the best solution here be to just create two separate inverse properties in User (like $group1 and $group2) and then create a getGroup() getter method that just checks whether either of those properties is populated and returns the one that is?

Is there a less hacky method I'm not thinking of? Appreciate any advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation so I have created a third table with manyToOne to User, manyToOne to Group and one field that says if this user for this group is manager. So you can do the same add and two fields that states if user is senior or junior.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution is to do a "one to one Unidirectional" association in both group and user entities, so the code for your group will be :

```
class Group
{

     private idGroup;
    /**
     * 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="seniorModerator_id", referencedColumnName="idUser")
     */
    private $seniorModerator;

    /**
     * 
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="juniorModerator_id", referencedColumnName="idUser")
     */
    private $juniorModerator;

}
```

For your User :

```
class User{
    private idUser;

    /**
    *
    * @oneToOne(targetEntity="Group")
    * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="idGroup")
    */
    private $group;
}
```

if you want more information on Association Mapping hir are the documentation : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: Those would have to be updated independently though, wouldn't they? In other words, if a user is set as the junior moderator for a group, $group wouldn't automatically be populated appropriately in the User entity unless I'm misunderstanding?